# How to set data source of a server side panel using javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik, datasource

I have a JSON formatted fetched data. I want to set this data as a data-source for a server-side Control Panel. Is there any method in JavaScript that allows me to do this? Or which way i could follow. I have tried it with the code below but it did not work.
Thanks in advance.

```
      success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#<%=ControlPanel.ClientID%>").set_dataSource(response);

                    }
```

Comment: By the time your JavaScript runs, your ASP.NET page has already finished executing. Within a basic page lifecycle, you can’t update a server-side control using a client side variable, unless that control outputs code that supports e.g., client-side data-binding or some type of AJAX integration. Instead, you’d usually need to either post the data back to the server, or submit the data via an AJAX request. For WebForms, you might consider looking into either Page Methods or an UpdatePanel as a quick and easy way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I don't want to use server control at all. No round trip is wanted once data is fetched? Is this impossible? the Front end has been designed with Telerik UI. I want to rewrite some existed functions with JavaScript to avoid unnecessary calls to the server?

Comment: It might be? I haven’t worked with Telerik’s controls in a long time, but I recall that most of them include client side data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you question doesnt cover the whole scenario regarding the why you want to do it with JS only..

1. Why don't you access data directly from server side scripting
2. I don't see if you can do it the way you want it as it may have other issue such as page will be rendered before your JS will execute so you cant access the value when you your page is already be rendered, so only way around i see is that you assign this value to a hidden field and then do a partial update so that this data in JSON format will be available to server control, but still you will have to write the logic as i don't know what exactly you are doing or why?

provide more details to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: The main idea behind this move is to increase the app's responsiveness. Every event in the current scenario has got something to do with back end which slows down the app. The idea is if possible to carry out some of the event  in front end and there will be no unnecessary calls to server. For example, I have a button whose job is to populate some comboxes. This action is for now handled by ascx.cs file Code behind. It freezes the app for a while after a click. We want to get rid of this by implementing javascript functions for instance for every click functions, or combo box selection.

Comment: The why dont you create a webservice in backend call from front end using ajax that should improve response time..